# Ruby on Rails add models for existing plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I am new to Ruby On Rails, and currently trying to modify an existing (uncomplete) plugin from github. Things went smoothly until I am trying to add new models to this plugin.

I know script/generate model, and script/generate plugin. But how to add models into a plugin without regenerate the whole plugin? I don't want rewrite the plugin to add functions to it, and script/generate model vendor/plugin/myPlugin wilt generate other stuff into the whole project rather than the plugin directory.

Probably I could write the model class file myself, but how about migration, create my own rake file?

Note: The plugin has more than one classes and a couples of migrate schema named as datetime_create_model_name.rb. But I couldn't find any generator in the plugin Dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a `generator` for the plugin, to create the migration scripts for the new model. Refer to some of the existing plugins, to learn how to write a generator.

Here is one example:

1) [Generator file](http://github.com/kandadaboggu/vote_fu/blob/master/generators/vote_fu/vote_fu_generator.rb)

2) [Migration template file](http://github.com/kandadaboggu/vote_fu/blob/master/generators/vote_fu/templates/migration.rb)

Comment: Hi, KandadaBoggu, as my notes, there is no generator file in the plugin folder, but a few migration files, how did those migration classes been created?

Comment: En, seems make sense, is the time stamp in the file name required by rake db:migrate ?

Comment: No. Its really up to you to decide if you need the time-stamp fields in your model.